# Confused about main difference among query parsers in Solr

Tags: search, solr

I am pretty new to Solr, when I met the concept of query parser such as basicLucene, dismax, edismac etcs, I wonder what is the main difference among them? Is it the way it scoring fields? What should I pay the major attention to when I just want a simple keyword (or boolean logic combination) search (which may involve specifying field)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard will suffice for simple boolean manipulation and querying by fields. If you need some special features, do look at others just to see if they perform better for your needs.

### About parsers

There are number of differences (allowed syntax, features, error handling), but first let's state what a parser does: it takes query text as submitted and converts it into Lucene Query object, that Solr/Lucene combo can understand and use when searching.

Lucene parser is the default one. It has fairly intuitive syntax, but lacks power. It works with Solr recommended operators (+ and -) as well as with not recommended Boolean ones (AND, OR, NOT).

Dismax parser was aimed for simple consumer-apps: "more Google-like" and "less stringent". It rarely throws errors (compared to standard one), works with + and - to avoid inner query building problem and it's name stems from Maximum Dysjunction:

> A query that generates the union of documents produced by its
>   subqueries, and that scores each document with the maximum score for
>   that document as produced by any subquery, plus a tie breaking
>   increment for any additional matching subqueries.

EDixMax was DisMax Extended - with more power / features added. See links at the bottom for full feature list, but it basically allows to use full Lucene syntax (which neither standard Solr nor DisMax parser didn't).

More? Sure! There's LOTS of parsers, some by Lucene team, some by Solr team, some by others. See third link below for full list and some info.

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers